# Evaluating The Upper Incomplete Gamma Function With A Negative Integration Bound

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, gamma-function

I need to evaluate:

$$ \Gamma(a,-x, \infty) = \int_{-x}^{\infty} t^{a-1} e^{-t} dt$$

When I plug this into Wolfram, for instance $Gamma[\frac{1}{2}, -4]$ I get a complex number. How is this calculated?

Comment: why does your incomplete gamma have $3$ arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally there is a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04152) by A. Gil, D. Ruiz-Antolín, J. Segura, N. M. Temme from Aug. 14, which describes the computation of Tricomi's incomplete gamma function, this function $\gamma^{*}(a, z)$ is real for real positive and negative values of $a$ and $z$ and can be defined as
$$\gamma^{*}(a,z)  = \frac{z^{-a}}{\Gamma(a)}\gamma(a,z)$$

If you have access to this function you can compute
$$\Gamma(a,z)=\Gamma(a)-\gamma(a,z)
=\Gamma(a)\Big(1-z^a\gamma^{*}(a,z)\Big)$$

Here is the example with $a=1/2, z=-4$ from my own Pascal library:
$\gamma^{*}(1/2,-4) = 9.2824012072877763$ and therefore 
$$\Gamma(1/2,-4) = \sqrt{\pi}(1-\sqrt{-4}\times 9.2824012072877763) \\=
1.7724538509055160-32.905255531014461 i$$

If you have access to Kummer's confluent hypergeometric $M$ function (sometimes called $_1 F_1$)
you can express the entire Tricomi function for all $a,z \in \mathbb{C}$
as (see [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.5))
$$
\gamma^{*}(a,z) = e^{-z} \; \frac{M(1,a+1,z)}{\Gamma(a+1)}
= e^{-z} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{\Gamma(a+n+1)}.
$$
This confluent hypergeometric form is used by my routine for real $z<0,\,$ i.e.
$$\gamma^{*}(1/2,-4)= \frac{e^4 M(1,3/2,-4)}{\Gamma(3/2)}= \\
54.5981500331442391 \times 0.150670194461895983 / 0.886226925452758014 = 9.2824012072877763$$

Comment: Hm! Okay! I will have to try this out and let you know. I need to figure out how to compute M or 1F1 first...

Answer (score 0):

The upper incomplete gamma function is defined as such:
$$\Gamma(s,x) = \int_x^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$
In your case you are asking about
$$\Gamma(1/2,-4) = \int_{-4}^\infty t^{-1/2}e^{-t}dt$$
Note that this is only real for $t>0$... for $t<0$ we have that $t^{1/2}$ is an imaginary number, therefore making the integral complex over this region. This should generalize to an arbitrary negative lower bound of integration.

Comment: Correct. However can't I just:

$$ \Gamma(1/2, -4) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-1/2}e^{-t}dt - \int_{0}^{4} t^{-1/2}e^{t} dt$$

I suppose I have to deal with limiting behavior then. Not quite sure where the complex numbers come in here...

Comment: @TheDude your upper limit should still be $-4$. I'm on mobile right now so I won't go into much detail until later if you need it, but the negative sign in front of the second integral only switches the upper and lower limits... It DOESN'T change the sign on the limits! The integral from $0$ to $-4$ is almost entirely complex (except at the single point $t=0$, which isn't even defined anyway. The original integral still converges nevertheless)

Comment: Ah, duh. Welp...